# Laravel 4 - Reusable code

Tags: laravel-4

I have run into a small problem. I have a site built that only has a web interface at the moment, but I want to expand and build a REST API for a mobile app. The problem is, my controllers return blade views, and not a JSON response. How would I go about writing the code for my API? It almost seems as if I will have to copy and paste code and then format it to return JSON, but that would create quite the headache for patching bugs. Any thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an REST API first web application in Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115291/how-to-make-an-rest-api-first-web-application-in-laravel)

Comment: Evidently I was searching for the wrong keywords.  I found what I needed.