# Laravel and repository/gateway patterns. Did I lose the fillable property for future helper?

Tags: laravel, repository-pattern

I'm following this answer with his pattern:

[How to make a REST API first web application in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115291/how-to-make-a-rest-api-first-web-application-in-laravel)

At the end my application works with these methods:

**LanController**

```
/**
     *
     * Store the data in database
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector|void
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $status = $this->lan_gateway->create($request->all());
        /**
         * Status is true if insert in database is OK
         * or an array of errors
         */
        if ($status===true) {
            return redirect(route('lan'))
                ->with('success',trans('common.operation_completed_successfully'));
            // validation ok
        } else {
            return redirect(route('lan-create'))
                ->withInput()
                ->withErrors($status);
            // validation fails
        }
    }
```

**LanGateway**

```
/**
     * Validate input and create the record into database
     *
     * @param array $data the values to insert
     * @return array $validator errors on fails
     * @return bool $status true on success
     */
    public function create(array $data)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'ip_address' => 'required|string'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $validator->errors()->all();
        } else {
            $status = $this->lan_interface->createRecord($data);
            return $status;
        }

    }
```

And this is the interface implemented by repository `create` method

```
<?php
/**
 * Repository for LAN object.
 * PRG paradigma, instead of "User"-like class Model
 *
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115291/how-to-make-a-rest-api-first-web-application-in-laravel
 */

namespace App\Repositories;
use App\Interfaces\LanInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class LanRepository extends Model implements LanInterface
{

    /**
     * The name of table on database
     * @var string The table name on database
     */
    protected $table = "lans";

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['ip_address'];

    public function getAllRecords()
    {
        $lan = $this->all();
        return $lan;
    }

    /**
     *
     * Insert record inside database.
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return bool true on success, false on failure
     */
    public function createRecord(array $data)
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (in_array($key,$this->fillable)) {
                $this->$key = $value;
            }
        }
        $status = $this->save();
        return $status;
    }
```

You can see that I "lost" the fillable helper methods, at the end I use only as "needle/haystack".

Is there another implementation possible for my `createRecord` method to use, as much as possible, Laravel default methods/helpers or am I in the most right direction?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment), $fillable property only applies when you are using mass assignment statements.

Now if `if (in_array($key,$this->fillable)) {` conditional check is just to check if only some allowed set of columns are saved from API, you can create another property lets say `protected $allowedToInsert = ['column1', 'column2],..;` and then update the conditional :

```
public function createRecord(array $data)
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (in_array($key,$this->allowedToInsert)) {
                $this->$key = $value;
            }
        }
        $status = $this->save();
        return $status;
    }
```

This way you can use `fillable` as it is supposed to be used, The approach you have can be the simplest one but you can improve lit of things. See [this](https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial) for your reference